# error cuando utilizo .write en python

Tags: python

```
from io import open
archivo_texto=open("ar.txt","a")
archivo_texto.write("dertin\n")
archivo_texto.close()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "externos.py", line 5, in
>   
>       archivo_texto.write("dertin\n") TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str

Comment: aun asi no me muestra el mismo error

Comment: Abrelo en modo "ab", o pasa la cadena  a Unicode, o usa python3

Comment: con el modo ab si corre perfecto gracias

Comment: ¿por que sucede ese problema?

Comment: abre el archivo en formato binario , a=append , b= binary

Comment: A todo esto: archivo_texto=open("ar.txt","a")
No conozco el modo de acceso "a" ¿Para que sirve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Por qué sucede ese problema?

Buff... respuesta laarga... espero que tengas realmente *mucho* interés ;-)

La codificación de caracteres es un caballo de batalla constante en la informática, puesto que lo que guardamos en un fichero (o enviamos por la red) no es más en realidad que una secuencia de bits, y para saber qué significa (qué caracteres representan), es necesario usar alguna tabla de códigos que haga una equivalencia entre grupos de bits y caracteres.

### Un poco de historia

El ASCII es la más antigua de esa tabla de códigos. Se usó (y se sigue usando) porque utiliza 7 bits para representar los caracteres, con lo que cabe en un byte y aún le sobra un bit (originalmente usado como bit de paridad de los otros siete, pero enseguida "sobrante" y puesto al valor 0 en cuanto se comenzaron a usar métodos de detección de errores mejores que la simple paridad).

El grave inconveniente del ASCII es que con 7 bits tiene para 128 caracteres diferentes, y si descuentas los 32 códigos usados como "controles" (no imprimibles), quedan 96 símbolos, para almacenar las minúsculas, mayúsculas, dígitos y otros signos, del alfabeto inglés. Caracteres como la eñe no forman parte del ASCII y no digamos ya juegos de caracteres más exóticos como el japonés, chino, cirílico, árabe, etc. Todo eso no es representable en ASCII.

Aprovechando el bit sobrante de ASCII muchos fabricantes vieron la oportunidad de meter otros 128 símbolos en la tabla, llamándolo "ASCII extendido", pero no había un estándar por lo que el símbolo con número 129 para un fabricante representaba una letra y para otro otra.

Ha habido bastantes estandarizaciones de esas tablas de 8 bits en las que el primer bit indicaba si era un carácter ASCII (si valía 0) o uno "propio de otra codificación", si valía 1. Algunas de las codificaciones más famosas de 8 bits son `cp1252`, usada (todavía) por Windows, `macroman` usada por Macintosh (ya no), `iso-8859-1` e `iso-8859-15`, también llamadas `latin-1` y `latin-9` (sí, 9, no es un error), etc. Y sólo enumero las que usamos por aquí, que son las que contienen la eñe, las vocales acentuadas, etc. Otros paises usan sus propias tablas.

Todo este "caos" terminó con la llegada de Unicode, que unifica en una sola (monstruosa) tabla todos los alfabetos del mundo, y muchas más cosas que no son alfabetos (signos matemáticos, signos musicales, alfabetos de fantasía, emojis...) Naturalmente esto renuncia ya a utilizar 8 bits por caracter. Cada código Unicode requiere unos 21 bits, pero típicamente se usa algún múltiplo de 8, como 32 bits (de los que se dejan sin usar los 11 superiores), o 16 bits (que no son suficientes para guardar cualquier código Unicode, pero sí los 65536 más frecuentes, suficientes para los alfabetos de las lenguas vivas).

A la hora de guardar en fichero o transmitir por la red texto Unicode, es necesaro convertir esos 21 ó 32 bits en una secuencia de bytes, para lo que suele usarse el estándar utf8, aunque otros son posibles, como utf16. Pero no son diferentes tablas de códigos, todos son unicode, son simplemente diferentes formas de "trocear" en bytes los códigos Unicode.

### Python2

En python 2 hay dos tipos de cadena. La habitualmente utilizada, tipo `str` y la unicode, tipo `unicode`. Cuando en tu programa pones algo entre comillas como "Esto", será de tipo `str`. Si pones una `u` delante, será de tipo `unicode`.

Una cadena `unicode` es lo que realmente entenderíamos por "texto", pues cada elemento de esa cadena representa un carácter muy concreto, y es almacenado en memoria mediante un código Unicode (de 32 bits, en python).

Una cadena `str` en cambio no es más que una secuencia de bytes "sin sentido" para python. Los bytes que hay ahí son los que haya puesto tu editor de texto dentro de las comillas. Por ejemplo, al poner en un editor esta línea:

```
data = "Eñe"
```

y guardarlo en un archivo `.py`, lo que realmente guardas son ciertos códigos binarios que, al volcarlos por una terminal o abrirlos de nuevo en el editor, se ven como un programa python. La mayoría de esos códigos serán ASCII (pues los nombres de variables en python, los operadores, etc. son todos símbolos ASCII), pero lo que pongas dentro de las comillas o en los comentarios puede no ser ASCII. Tu editor usará una codificación concreta a la hora de guardar esa parte en el archivo `.py`. Por ejemplo, si lo escribes en Windows, usará la codificación `cp1252`, o tal vez `utf8`, según el editor.

Cuando python ejecuta ese programa se limita a guardar en memoria, para la variable `data` lo que sea que tu editor haya puesto ahí, sin entender realmente qué significa. Puede realizar algunas operaciones con esos bytes, suponiendo que son ASCII, pero si no son ASCII los resultados pueden no ser los esperados (por ejemplo, intenta pasar a mayúsculas con `data.upper()`, todo lo que no sea ASCII no lo pasará a mayúsculas). Puede incluso fallar en cosas tan importantes como en `len(data)`, ya que la cantidad de bytes de la cadena no tiene por qué coincidir con la cantidad de letras que tenga.

Por tanto para el manejo de texto es mejor usar el tipo `unicode`, con algo como:

```
data = u"Eñe"
```

En este caso las funciones `.upper()` o `.len()` sí que tendrán ya el comportamiento esperado. Aunque para poder obtener los códigos Unicode que corresponden al texto que has escrito, python2 necesita saber qué codificación usó tu editor. Y por eso hay que poner un comentario como:

```
# coding: cp1252
```

al principio del programa

#### Entrada/Salida

Cuando imprimes con `print(data)` una variable de tipo `str`, python no hace nada especial con ella. Se limita a enviar a la terminal la secuencia de bytes que contuviera. Si la terminal usa la misma codificación que usó el editor en que se escribió el programa, el texto se leerá correctamente. Si no, se verán correctamente los caracteres ASCII, pero se verán probablemente mal los no-ascii.

Cuando imprimes con `print(data)` una variable de tipo `unicode`, python debe convertir su representación interna (Unicode) a algo que la terminal pueda entender, para lo que necesita conocer qué codificación entiende la terminal. Intentará averiguar ésto de alguna forma, pero si no lo consigue asumirá que es ASCII, e intentará convertir a ASCII cada letra que imprima, y fallará (estrepitosamente, con un error como `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)` cuando encuentre letras no-ascii).

Puedes ser explícito y hacer tú mismo la conversión de Unicode a ASCII especificando un encoding concreto:

```
data = u"Eñe"
print(data.encode("utf8"))
```

Pero si la terminal no entiende utf8, no se verá bien.

Cuando, en vez de la terminal, quieres escribir en un fichero, tienes dos opciones:

- Abrir el fichero en modo binario (añadiendo una `"b"` al modo). En este modo cualquier secuencia de bytes (`str`) que envíes, se escribirá sin transformarla en modo alguno y sin intentar "entender" qué caracteres representa. La codificación del fichero de texto resultante será ASCII si todo lo que volcaste en él era ASCII, o será cp1252 si el código fuente lo escribiste en un editor con esa codificación, etc.
- Abrir el fichero en modo texto (omitir la `"b"` en el modo). En este modo python espera que lo que envíes a fichero con `write` sea Unicode y él se ocupará de convertirlo a una codificación concreta (que puedes especificar también al abrir el fichero, o que será ASCII por defecto).

Así pues ya podemos responder tu pregunta:

> ¿Por qué sucede ese problema?

Tú habías abierto en modo texto, pero después en el write usaste una cadena "normal" (`str`). Python se quejó de que necesitaba una cadena Unicode.

A la luz de lo antes dicho, lo siguiente podría ser también una solución:

```
archivo_texto.write(u"dertin\n")
```

lo cual en este caso funcionaría perfectamente porque lo que hay dentro de las comillas es ascii válido, pero podría producirte errores si dentro de las comillas apareciera una eñe u otro caracter no-ascii.

## Python3

En python 3 se decidió que el tipo `str` fuera ya unicode. Todo lo que aparece en tu programa entre comillas se codifica internamente como unicode. Si por alguna razón necesitas trabajar con cadenas "de bytes", debes especificarlo poniendo una `b` delante de las comillas, o convirtiendo las cadenas unicode en cadenas de bytes especificando una codificación concreta.

Cuando abres un fichero, por defecto es texto y se presupone una codificación "utf8".

En Python3 tu programa:

```
from io import open
archivo_texto=open("ar.txt","a")
archivo_texto.write("dertin\n")
archivo_texto.close()
```

funciona sin problemas, pues `"dertin\n"` es una cadena de texto (internamente unicode), y el archivo se ha abierto en modo texto. Al escribir en él, la cadena de texto se convierte en cadena de bytes utf-8 (puedes especificar otra codificación al abrir el archivo).

Comment: Un poquito larga tu respuesta pero muy detallada e informativa! +1