# Error con el write python

Tags: python

No me escribe nada en el archivo de texto

```
from io import open 

archivo_texto=open("archivo.txt", "w")
frase="Estupendo dia para estudiar python  el miercoles"
archivo_texto.write(frase)
archivo_texto.close()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: prueba utilizando el prefijo u""   frase=u"Estupendo dia para estudiar python  el miercoles"

Answer (score 3):

El error te dice que el parámetro que envias debe ser unicode *(OJO que en python 3 tu codigo corre con normalidad)*.

En todo caso prueba con:

```
from io import open

archivo_texto=open("archivo.txt", "w")
frase="Estupendo dia para estudiar python  el miercoles"
archivo_texto.write(frase.decode('utf-8'))
archivo_texto.close()
```

o bien con

```
from io import open

archivo_texto=open("archivo.txt", "w")
frase=u"Estupendo dia para estudiar python  el miercoles"
archivo_texto.write(frase)
archivo_texto.close()
```

Y ahora explicamos porque sucede el error:

### Python2

En python 2 hay dos tipos de cadena. La habitualmente utilizada, tipo *str* y la unicode, tipo unicode. Cuando en tu programa pones algo entre comillas como "Esto", será de tipo *str*. Si pones una u delante, será de tipo **unicode**.

Una cadena **unicode** es lo que realmente entenderíamos por "texto", pues cada elemento de esa cadena representa un carácter muy concreto, y es almacenado en memoria mediante un código Unicode (de 32 bits, en python).

Una cadena str en cambio no es más que una secuencia de bytes "sin sentido" para python. Los bytes que hay ahí son los que haya puesto tu editor de texto dentro de las comillas. Por ejemplo, al poner en un editor esta línea:

```
data = "Eñe"
```

y guardarlo en un archivo `.py`, lo que realmente guardas son ciertos códigos binarios que, al volcarlos por una terminal o abrirlos de nuevo en el editor, se ven como un programa python. La mayoría de esos códigos serán *ASCII* (pues los nombres de variables en python, los operadores, etc. son todos símbolos *ASCII*), pero lo que pongas dentro de las comillas o en los comentarios puede no ser *ASCII*. Tu editor usará una codificación concreta a la hora de guardar esa parte en el archivo .py. Por ejemplo, si lo escribes en Windows, usará la codificación cp1252, o tal vez utf8, según el editor.

Cuando python ejecuta ese programa se limita a guardar en memoria, para la variable data lo que sea que tu editor haya puesto ahí, sin entender realmente qué significa. Puede realizar algunas operaciones con esos bytes, suponiendo que son ASCII, pero si no son ASCII los resultados pueden no ser los esperados *(por ejemplo, intenta pasar a mayúsculas con `data.upper()`, todo lo que no sea *ASCII* no lo pasará a mayúsculas)*. Puede incluso fallar en cosas tan importantes como en `len(data)`, ya que la cantidad de bytes de la cadena no tiene por qué coincidir con la cantidad de letras que tenga.

Por tanto para el manejo de texto es mejor usar el tipo *unicode*, con algo como:

```
data = u"Eñe"
```

En este caso las funciones `.upper()` o `.len()` sí que tendrán ya el comportamiento esperado. Aunque para poder obtener los códigos *Unicode* que corresponden al texto que has escrito, python2 necesita saber qué codificación usó tu editor. Y por eso hay que poner un comentario como:

```
# coding: cp1252
```

al principio del programa

### Python3

En python 3 se decidió que el tipo *str* fuera ya *unicode*. Todo lo que aparece en tu programa entre comillas se codifica internamente como *unicode*. Si por alguna razón necesitas trabajar con cadenas *"de bytes"*, debes especificarlo poniendo una b delante de las comillas, o convirtiendo las cadenas *unicode* en cadenas de bytes especificando una codificación concreta.

Cuando abres un fichero, por defecto es texto y se presupone una codificación "utf8".

---

Fuentes que te invito a revisar:

- https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html
- https://www.pythond.com/23468/por-que-declarar-unicode-por-cadena-en-python.html
- [error cuando utilizo .write en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174269/error-cuando-utilizo-write-en-python)

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)